# IOS: launch image multiple language

Tags: ios, xcode, uilaunchimagefile

I have a multiple language app. 
My problem is launch image, what's the way to use a launch image according to language of device. Is there something in `info.plist` file?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The solution is to localize Default.png like any other resource in your project. Select Default.png from project list in Xcode, on the right pane find "Localization" and simply add new localizations. After that you can change the files to be different for all localizations.

1. In project summary pane in Xcode (talking about Xcode 4.2) add launch images for one or both orientations as normally.
2. Launch images will appear in your project files list. Select one of them.
3. Expand Utilities (the pane on the right), you will see following groups: "Indentity and Type", "Image Properties", "Localization", ... . In localization group click "+" button. You can now add new localization (for example Spanish).
4. After that on the left of your file in project list you will see an expand button. Click the button to show files for all localizations.
5. Your localized Default.png files will appear in .lproj directories in project directory. You can for example manually swipe the file in en.lproj to change english launch image.

Comment: can you explain how to do it?

Comment: it's all ok but in point 4, now if i expand file I see three file (example english, spanish, frech); but these three file are all identical; I want that every file is different, and it change according to language; then I want to change file for english and franch (for example)

Comment: right click on one of that files, choose "Show in finder", you will go to .lproj directory. Now you can change your file. After that clean your build, because Xcode may not catch the changes.

Comment: I followed all the steps but my translated images are not being used. Even after I clean the build...

Comment: This approach works great while developing and testing the app using Xcode. When uploading binary to itunesconnect.com it goes from "upload received" to "invalid binary" in exactly 2 minutes.
And then I receive an email "iPhone 5 Optimization Requirement - Your binary is not optimized for iPhone 5. ..." explaining that I need to provide launch images in a correct way like I haven't specified them at all.

Comment: @ancajic I have the same symptoms: works perfectly on both simulators and test devices, however after submission I get `iPhone 5 Optimization Requirement - Your binary is not optimized for iPhone 5` which is very misleading to say the least. Have you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Apple's HIG document advises that developers use launch images that don't have any text whatsoever. Take the contacts app for instance, it simply displays an empty UI so the user believes the app to be launching quicker.

So I suggest following this approach and removing any traces of language from the launch images.

Comment: But if you have an app with totally custom interface, and for example splash screen with app logo and name, it is good for launch image to look like a first frame of splash screen. Then if you are localizing your app name for example, you could also localize Default.png in the same way like any other resource.

Comment: I agree it seems odd that this isn't an option, but once again Apple suggests not having a splash screen. Even if you have a custom UI, just remove all the text and use that as your launch image.

Comment: I understand Apple suggestions, and always try to follow that as much as it is possible, but some times I'm making some exceptions like that. My company has several apps in store with this kind of practices  and it was not any trouble with submission to App Store.

Comment: Ok after some Googling it looks like you may actually be able to do this, check out the documentation here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/App-RelatedResources/App-RelatedResources.html