# Localize launch image just for english?

Tags: ios, localization

I have a launch image Default-568h@2x.png which I've localized for English (it sits in my en.lproj folder). Now I'd like to produce one other version of that image for every other language (I've removed the english text from it). How would I go about setting this up? I've tried putting an image with the same name in the top directory but that doesn't work. Do I need to rename to something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I did was go into my actual project folder and put the english version of my launch image into a folder called "Launch Image (English)". Then I put the version for the rest of the languages in a folder called "Launch Image (International)" (both images have the exact same name). Then I went into Xcode and attached both folders into the resources section. Then I highlighted each image, clicked on localization in the Utility pane, and for the english version I selected english obviously, and for the other version I selected spanish (then I put a check mark in the check box of each other language in the Utility pane). Then it worked!

Answer (score 1):

Basically, when you localize to any language (eg: Spanish), you will see another folder such as "**es.lproj**", the Localizable.strings and other localized files will be there.

You may check http://www.raywenderlich.com/64401/internationalization-tutorial-for-ios-2014 
for the step by step instruction on how to do it including localize the image.

Another link that might help: [IOS: launch image multiple language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9411308/ios-launch-image-multiple-language)