# Launch image from code (Paintcode)

Tags: ios, core-graphics, paintcode

I have a launch image with text, that I'd like to internationalize (I know that Apple doesn't like launch images with text though...).

It would be great, if I could do this in code, because then the footprint of the app will be much smaller.

Is it possible to do so and how would I access the launch image? I know the the app icon can't be created dynamically by code, thats why I guess the launch image might follow the same rule.

Thanks.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/a/9411515/1491063

Comment: @Theodoros80: No, it was not about i18n of assets in general, but if the launch image has to be a 'real' (png, jpg) image, or if it can be drawn by code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean the Default.png, no you can't.
As you mentioned, you can localize them but it will raise your app size.

One possible solution is to make a really quick app start and a launch image without a text and right after your app launch (`-applicationDidFinishLaunching` may be appropriate) you display a pseudo splashscreen with your localized text for n seconds.

But keep in mind this isn't nice nor something apple wants.

Comment: You should try running ImageOptim on your images. Xcode does some of this already, but ImageOptim may do a more thorough job for some images.

Answer (score 1):

This can not be done, since the launch image is in the application bundle which is readonly.

You could however present a second screen just after launching, if you make sure you do not do anything in the `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` but show you seconds splashscreen it will only show the `default.png` for a very short time.