# Localization LaunchScreen ios7 and ios8

Tags: ios, localization, internationalization, launch-screen

I have a problem with LaunchScreen.

My application support multiple languages.

I have got 4 launch screens with different text.

I don't know how to localize this images.

I need xcode 6 and ios7 support.

I tried adding Default@2x.png and localized this file, but on my iphone the  launchscreen don't appear.

Any suggestions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [IOS: launch image multiple language](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9411308/ios-launch-image-multiple-language)