# Localizing storyboard Launchscreen

Tags: xcode, storyboard, launch-screen

Is it possible to localize the Launchscreen in storyboard?
I have an image for English and for French, I need to localize them in Launchscreen.

Please this is important to solve this issue by any means.

If there is any tips or trick, please let me know...

**UPDATE**
@Martin R This topic is not duplicate, you are refereing a solution of older xcode.
Older xcode we used to use `Default.png`, but newer xcode we use  `LaunchScreen.storyboard`.
How can we localize the `LaunchScreen.storyboard` if I have two images of 2 different languages?

Comment: I believe at the moment, launch screen cannot be localized. In the human interface guide they warned ONLY on text being static, and not localizable. But clearly we cannot localize images too. iOS simply ignore localized version of the launch screen storyboard.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, I find all the documents has not found the contents of the localization of Launchscreen.

Here my situation:

The document of Launch screen ([Launch Screen](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/graphics/launch-screen/)) suggest using static images:

> Avoid including text on your launch screen. Because launch screens are
>   static, any displayed text won’t be localised.
>
> It’s best to use an Xcode storyboard for your launch screen, but you can provide a set of static images if necessary. Create static
>   images in different sizes for different devices, and be sure to
>   include the status bar region.

It does not say whether the picture can be localized,so I localised the launch image resources like this: [Launch image multiple language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9411308/ios-launch-image-multiple-language). But I failed like this [Can't get correct localized launch images on IOS 9](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/22674).

It's launch images can't be localized: [Localized launch images were never officially supported](https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/74000#74000)?